# Does anyone have a copy of Jordi Quer's thesis?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, elliptic-curves

I am interested in some of Jordi Quer's early work, particularly his work on finding imaginary quadratic number fields with high 3-rank. This work was done in the late 80's. I am sure his thesis contains some nice work on this subject but I am having difficulty tracking it down. I am wondering if anyone has a copy of it?

Comment: I'm not sure it's on the Internet.  I think I found the title of the thesis [here](https://www.genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=42314) then found a link to the online repository [here](https://www.uab.cat/web/study/phds/published-theses-1345688357239.html), which is [TDX](https://www.tdx.cat/handle/10803/120?locale-attribute=en), but it only contains 124 theses, the earliest I found was from 1991.  You might reach out to the author or the UAB university library, who likely still has it on file.

Comment: A search on WorldCat finds that UAB and a handful of other university libraries have a copy. For example: https://www.worldcat.org/title/sobre-el-3-rang-dels-cossos-quadratics-i-la-corba-elliptica-y2x3-m/oclc/802664639
I can't find an online copy either, so I agree that the best bet would be to email the author, and if you don't get a response, reach out to the UAB library and see if they could scan it or something (assuming you're not close enough to reasonably travel there).